# Overlayed resizable images using css

Tags: html, css

I've a series of img of the same size, now I would like that these image are overlayed, one on the other. For this I've set the position of the image to absolute, but in this way the problem is that the container have not the right size because the image are absolute positioned...

Furthermore the images must be resizable according to the browser size

Someone know a solution for insert some images overlayed?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="image1" />
            <img src="image2" />
            <img src="image3" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the div container must obtain the size of the 3 img, all img have the same size, and must be overlayed each other...

Comment: Would you prefer some javascript script?

Comment: in this case I would avoid to use some javascript script because there are some other javascrit code executing in that moment

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set only one of them to be relative by using something like

```
#container img:first-of-type {
    position:relative;
}
```

The relative image will set the size, and the absolute ones will just lay on top (or behind) even if you re-arrange the order.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for multiple images set in `background-image` css property.

CSS:

```
#container {
  background-image: url('image1'), url('image2'), url('image3');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  /*background-size: cover; - alternatively, see the explanation below */
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Using `background-size: cover|contain;` ensures that the images will be properly scaled by the browser to always fit the actual dimensions of the `#container`.

---

How does `background-size: cover;` behave?

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

How does `background-size: contain;` behave?

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

---

References/further reading:

- [Multiple Backgrounds with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)
- [background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)